# Finding a certain header and copying a certain amount of entries below it

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search for a certain header (Header 1 in this example) and copy a certain amount of cells below this header to a range. The text of the header itself isn't supposed to get copied but everything below it.

The following code works, but it copies too many lines. When I use `For x = 0 To 3` it copies the next 10 lines below "Header 1" instead of only 3. I can't find my mistake.

```
Sub FindCopyPasteV2()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:FF")

        Dim FindEQ3 As Range
        Dim TestR As Range
        Dim x As Long

           Set FindEQ3 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

              For x = 0 To 3

                 Set FindEQ3 = FindEQ3.Resize(FindEQ3.Rows.Count + x).Offset(1)
                 Set TestR = .Range("K" & 5 + x)

                 FindEQ3.Copy TestR

              Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: hi. i dont understant the porpose of the FOR cycle.u are copyng 1 row, then 2 rows then 3 rows and then 4 rows.... how many rows do u want to copy ?

Comment: After finding "Header 1", I'm trying to use the loop to copy a certain amount of cells below this header to a different range. In the example above I'm trying to copy 3 lines under Header 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is just that you are doing something twice. The purpose of the loop is to make sure 3 rows get copied, but actually `FindEQ3.Resize` already does that.

This code should be closer to what you want. I mainly just took the loop out.

```
Sub FindCopyPasteV2()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:FF")

        Dim FindEQ3 As Range
        Dim TestR As Range

        Const NUM_ROWS_COPY As Long = 3

        Set FindEQ3 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        Set FindEQ3 = FindEQ3.Resize(NUM_ROWS_COPY).Offset(1)
        Set TestR = .Range("K" & 5)

        FindEQ3.Copy TestR


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The thing is, that in the next step I want to run a macro which reads the cells under the found "Header 1" and compares them to other values in a different place before (!) copying them. In preparation for the "advanced version" of this macro I wanted to use a loop instead of just copying the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use a for loop to copy a number of cells across. Please find below code. This should find the header you are after, then "copy" across the values else where.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindCopyPaste()

    Dim mRng As Range
    Dim fRng As Range
    Dim xOff As Long
    Dim mSheet As Worksheet

    'number of cells to "copy" across
    xOff = 3

    Set mSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set mRng = mSheet.Range("A:FF")
    Set fRng = mRng.Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)


    If Not fRng Is Nothing Then
        'if it finds the header
        'now set values
        mSheet.Range("K5").Resize(xOff, 1).Value = mSheet.Range(mSheet.Cells(fRng.Row + 1, fRng.Column), mSheet.Cells(fRng.Row + xOff, fRng.Column)).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Error! Could not find Header 1!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The thing is, that in the next step I want to run a macro which reads the cells under the found "Header 1" and compares them to other values in a different place before (!) copying them. In preparation for the "advanced version" of this macro I wanted to use a loop instead of just copying the cells.